# Windows 7 or Windows Vista with XNA for game development

Tags: windows, xna

I am on Windows XP 32-bit.

I want to learn XNA with a book that by the way, recommends Windows Vista or Windows 7.

Is it worth the trouble to transfer to those?

Thank you

Comment: Does the book explain why it recommends this? If so, pay attention to its rationale. If not, treat the recommendation with all the deference and respect you normally award unbidden advice from random strangers.

Comment: Nope, it just recommends it. The book is XNA 4.0 Game Development by Example.

Comment: Do you have any complaints about the XNA development experience that are specifically related to using XP. If not, don't bother. If so, go ahead and upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware and OS requirements for XNA:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203925.aspx

In short, you should be fine with XP unless you're targeting Windows Phone 7. The tools for that are not supported on XP.