# Xbox development not on Vista or 7

Tags: windows, xna, xbox

I've been looking into developing for Xbox and kinect, but I keep reading you need Windows vista or 7. Is there a workaround or anyway to use either a Mac, Linux, or Windows XP? I've tried to install XNA Studio and everything on XP, but it tells me to upgrade. I'd really rather not drop $150.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 or Windows Vista with XNA for game development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221906/windows-7-or-windows-vista-with-xna-for-game-development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search on this page for Standalone you'll see a download link.  This version lacks the windows phone set which required Windows 7.

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/resources/downloads

You can make xbox games, and kinect games for PC, but you can't make xbox-kinect games yet.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your currently part of the Xbox developer program, which is reserved for studios releasing Xbox games on DVD and Xbox Live Arcade, you can't use XNA Game Studio to create games using Kinect for the Xbox.

There is a Kinect SDK for Windows ( http://kinectforwindows.org/ ) that is currently in a preview state, which means it can't be used for commercial purposes.

Other than the Microsoft SDK's there is also the middleware and drivers from OpenNI ( http://openni.org ) and PrimeSense. Again, this still would only be for windows, not the Xbox, but may not require you to upgrade.